# symfony: using generator.yml, is there any way to hide the fields of the i18n forms in the admin?

Tags: symfony1

using generator.yml, is there any way to hide the fields of the i18n forms in the admin?

Javi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the form object try the useFields method

```
$this->useFields(array("field", "names", "you", "want", "to", "edit"));
```

In generator.yml

In the form section, or the fields/edit/new section. (Take your pick)

```
display: [field, names, you, want, to, edit]
```